# Getting specific data from returned response of Facebook API for android

Tags: java, android, facebook

Hi I'm currently new to Android development and I have a tasks to pass Facebook response using intent.

Here's my code in SplashActivity.java

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback(){
@Override
 public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, UserDetailsActivity.class);
        GraphObject responseGraphObject = response.getGraphObject();
    JSONObject userObj = responseGraphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
        intent.putExtra("userobj", userObj.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    SplashActivity.this.finish();
 }
}).executeAsync();
```

and in my UserDetailsActivity.java I received the intent data:

```
String userObj = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userobj");
```

The userObj looks like this: 
[image: Returned json]
How can I get specific data like first_name, last_name?, etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Parse the JsonString,Here is the great tutorial how to parse the [**`JsonString`**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

`{`-> jsonObject

`[`->jsonArray

```
JSONObject jobject =new JSONObject(responseString);
String firstname=jobject.getString("first_name");
String lastname=jobject.getString("last_name");
```